# Boostrap img reposive , not getting smaller in the navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i have a problem were i have my logo on the left hand side of my navbar and my navgation on the right hand side. Now as i am shrinking the screen i am trying to get the image to appear smaller so that the nav text and the image dont overlap each other.So basically a responsive design. However for some reason it does not seem to work at all,

I have used the `class="img-fluid` which boostrap says to use but it dosen't seem to work at all on the logo, so any help on this matter would be great

Fiidle Link : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35861/)

I have used float right on the nav bar and maybe thats what messes it up? but again i am not so sure how to get the image to be resposive and get smaller as the page shrinks

P.S As you can see in the fiddle , the image actually only starts to shrink when the window gets really small, almost less then the mobile version

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <div class="logo"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.martialartsschoolsdirectory.com/logos/profile/checkmat-logo-burbank-ca-184.png"></div>
        </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">NAVBARA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAVBARA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAVBARA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">NAVBARA</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: 6px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.navbar {
  padding-top: 53px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;



}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    height: 87px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      background-color: #F8BD23;
      text-decoration: none;
       color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left:30px;

}

body {

  background-color: black;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.logo img {width:100px;}

otherwise try 
add width="100" inside the img tag

Answer (score 0):

To make it shrink you have to make it inline-block and maybe use the following on the img tag:

```
style="display: inline-block; height: 40px; margin-top: 40px"
```

You can set whatever height and width you want